# Default IME Id parts?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-contentresolver, ime, android-input-method

I'm trying to get the IME of the device using this code:

```
String currentKeyboard = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

where `currentKeyboard` is `com.sec.android.inputmethod/.SamsungKeypad`.

- What does `com.sec.android.inputmethod` represents?
- And what does `/.SamsungKeypad` represents?

I know that the above code is to get the ID of the keyboard. By looking on the result, the ID of the keyboard should be `com.sec.android.inputmethod`.

- If `com.sec.android.inputmethod` is the keyboard ID, what does `/.SamsungKeypad` represents?
- What is the ID of the default keyboard of Android in vanilla flavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part `com.sec.android.inputmethod` is the package name of the entire default KeyBoard app. The one specified in the Android Manifest under `package`.

`.SamsungKeypad` is the name of the InputMethodService that is your explicit Keyboard in this case. The package contains everything: Setting, prediction algorithms, keyboard etc. This is just the keyboard. The default Latin keyboard is:

```
com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So basically, `com.sec.android.inputmethod` is a Samsung package? And `.SamsungKeypad` refers to its keyboard content since it contains many things aside from a keyboard. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Thank you! :) Got it. By the way, I think the default Latin keyboard is: `com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME`? I checked it using an emulator and it is what I got.

Comment: hmm.. why is there a different default keyboard package per device?

Comment: @LouisMorda It's an OEM specific app. Certain manufacturers make their own keyboards and put it as the default